# Image as Signature in CRM Email

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I came to a scenario where I need to send emails on create of lead but the signature of the user contains Image and that image should reflect in MSCRM email. That image should located after 'Thanks' and above 'User's job title' in email body for **CRM 11**.

Although I tried it in **MSCRM16** as well but no luck.

Is there any way to attach image in email body while sending it using system Workflow or custom workflow ?

Please help if there is any idea.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Best way to to do this is to host the images/signatures on public facing website and copy them in to your email templates , use those templates in your lead mails

In case you have users with different signatures then you need to have multiple templates, and based on the logged in user switch your templates

Please follow the links

[Email signatures](http://crmtipoftheday.com/2014/09/18/email-signatures/)

[CRM 2011 E-Mails–How to Insert / Add Graphics](https://mscrmmaster.com/2011/11/06/crm-2011-e-mailshow-to-insert-add-graphics/)

Comment: You mean, add image and that html page as web-resource in your CRM organization and then copy it from web page and paste into template, it works. :)